# SSRS - Dynamic Layout (Sort Of)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am struggling with how to create the following report.

A user selects the following parameter:
     Date Type:  "Day / Month / Year"

For date type, the layout for each is 100% different.  I have created three rectangles in my report to display.  It will hide the rectangles for the Date Type that are not selected and show the one that is selected.

To make this easy to maintain and enhance if needed, I have created all rectangles in a vertical line (instead of overlapping).  So Day Rectangle is at position 0, 0.  Month rectangle is at position 0,200 and year rectangle is at position 0,400).  This is done so I can see them all and makes maintaining and enhancing easier than having all three at position 0,0 (not sure how you move between them at that point)

How can I tell my report:  "If Day is selected.  Show Day and hide Month Year, but place Day Rectangle at the top left corner of the report (position 0,0).  If Month is selected, Hide Day / Year and show Month, but place Month rectangle at the top left corner of the report (position 0,0)

Comment: You cannot dynamically change the rectangle position(s), but you could potentially put  each rectangle into a separate row in a tablix and hide the rows you do not want shown. Hidden tablix rows should collapse.

Comment: Alternatively you could use 3 subreports and dynamically change which subreport is called based on the parameter value (subreport name is an expression)

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestions.  I will try these and one of them should work.  Appreciate the help.....